# How to select something from a textarea. Creating my editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I've been searching for a few hours, trying with so many different solutions but anything works for me.

I'm building my own text editor in jQuery, but now I'm facing a problem:

I have this code right now:

```
function bbcode() {

    var div = document.querySelector('textarea');
    var start = div.selectionStart;
    var finish = div.selectionEnd;
    var text = div.value.substring(start, finish);
    div.value('[b]' + text + '[/b]');

}
```

And this too:

```
$('#bold').click(function(evt) { bbcode(); });
```

**#bold** is a button and I want that when I click, it  adds me the first part of the bbcode ([b]), the text I've already selected and the last part of the bbcode.

But it doesn't work for me. Where's the problem?

Thanks for reading and helping.

PD: I hope I have explained well.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning it wrongly. value is not a function which accepts parameter. It is instead a property which can be assigned to.

```
div.value = '[b]' + text + '[/b]'; // setter
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hn007gmy/)

Comment: Yes, that's right. What a mistake! hahaha. I was mixing it with jQuery.